# Generating N urls to make AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, url-routing, javascript-objects

I'm facing a big problem after creating the API of a backend. I have a form with a GET AJAX method to filter and get results. It works fine but as the urls are generated from the users choice, there are N options I can't create each combination for when using or not each filter field.

Here is an example of one generated url:

`http://example.com/api/?select1=choice1&select2=choice2&tag=word&active=true`

Also if the user decides to chose only `select1` and `tag`

What I have done actually embarrases me as I know is not a good solution (not even close), and even to visualise it I just can't imagine how to get this to work but it looks like this:

```
select1 = $('#id_select1').find(":selected").text();
select2 = $('#id_select2').find(":selected").text();

if (select1 === "All" && select2 === "All") {
    url_get = '';
} else if (select1 === "All" && select2 !== "All") {
    url_get = 'select2=' + choice2
} else if (select2 === "All" && select1 !== "All"){
    url_get = 'select1=' + choice1
} else {
        url_get = 'choice1=' + select1 + '&' + 'choice2=' + select2
}
```

Is there a better way to keep going with this?
Any Javascript Ninja over there?

Comment: I would suggest letting the API handle blank params. By doing this, you can form your query as either "" if it's ALL, or the actual value. I can provide an example if you like.

EDIT: @gurvinder372's solution is exactly what I meant. On the API side you want to handle "" as ALL.

Comment: If you make it so that your API works without AJAX, i.e. use a standard HTML `<form>`, and deal with "All" values server-side, then the code will be super simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is using `.serialize()`: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

It will take your form and turn the name/value pairs and serialize it into a string.

An example:

```
var url_get = $('#myform').serialize();
```

Comment: I never imagine this could ever exist. Thanks @Shaazaam!

Answer (score 0):

Get mehotd in a URL from AJAX even if PURE Javascript read each param even if this param contains nothing

http://example.com/api/?select1=choice1&select2=&tag=word&active=

the problem is, how do you read that URL

**ASP Classic:**

```
Var1 = Request("select1")
Var2 = Request("select2")
Var3 = Request("tag")
Var4 = Request("active")
```

So in that case you should construct the URL even if the options are selected and there's no reason to "dinamic" construct the URL.

```
function send() {
    var1 = form.select1.value;
    var2 = form.select2.value;
    var3 = form.tag.value;       //in the case is an option
    var4 = form.active.value;    //same as before

    URL = "http://example.com/api/?select1="+var1+"&select2="+var2+ "&tag="+var3+"&active="+var4;

    (AJAX object).Open(GET, URL, True); //True is Async
    (AJAX object).onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if ((AJAX object).readyState == 4 && (AJAX object).status == 200) {
            //something
        } 
    }
    ajax.send(null); //Null since GET method
}
```

if you read in server side this variables are going to be in blank and there's no implication in that...

So depends what are you trying to do after this contruction, otherwise the context of this...